# Interesting logo use to show websites

Tags: jquery, ajax, effects

I found these websites:

http://www.robclarke.com/

http://work-play-work.com/

They have a near identical structure. I was just wondering if the effect they are using (the logo clicking and making a page appear) is a named effect or is it something new.

I looked at the source code and they don't seem to use a plugin for that effect.

Any one know anything?

Comment: "Any one know anything?" isn't a particularly constructive question, I think.

Comment: hmm...can't tell if serious or self-promoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's called ["SpaceCollective"](http://cargocollective.com/#/howitworks), and it's a proprietary layout of [Cargo](http://cargocollective.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some custom code written for the hosting website http://cargocollective.com/ - both of those websites look like they are hosted by that company.

Answer (score 0):

[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-complete.html) kind of does that.